# Find indices based on datetime

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Assume that I have the following data

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

numids = 3
start, end = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 15)
date_list = np.tile(pd.date_range(start, end, freq='B'), numids)
```

How do I find all indices where , say, `date_list == datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31)`? This should be an easy problem, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks, Tingis

**Edit**
If we take a simple example and set `numids` to `1` and the date of interest to be `datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)`, I would like to get the index `1`. Or a list `[True, False, False, ..., False]`.

**Edit 2**
Now, I try to just loop through the array and calculate the difference in days, such as

```
for date in date_list:
    print(date - datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 12))
```

However, this gives me an error that I've never seen

```
TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')
```

Comment: What are you looking for? all elements where date_list lies on that date?

Comment: Yes, well, all indices or a `True/False` list. Considering my example, I would (like) get three indices ,or a list of `True/False` where there are three `True`'s and the rest `False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this -

```
np.where(date_list == np.datetime64(datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31)))
>>> (array([ 63, 356, 649], dtype=int64),)
```